Could resistors give voltage?
Suppose we have the following circuit:

If I have used Kirchhoff's Voltage Law correctly the voltages should be as shown. However, to me it conveys something incomprehensible:
In loop 1, the current gains and loses 9 Volts to the top battery and middle horizontal resistor respectively. In outer loop 2, the current gains 9 Volts in the top battery, loses 18 in the left vertical resistor and then gains 9 in the lower battery again. Both these loops make sense to me but not the third.
In loop 3, we get +9 Volts from the battery and an apparent increase of 9 Volts in the middle horizontal resistor and then lose it all to the left vertical resistor.
My question is: how can we gain potential energy from a resistor? We must always lose voltage from it. If I'm missing something please point it out.

We definitely can gain voltage from resistors. Your example is one of them. It is a matter of the direction of the current and the direction of your traversal of the loop.

How could that physically work @naturallyInconsistent

It is not about physically work. The physics is perfectly fine. Your question is really down to the mathematical modelling of this important physics. You could walk in any loop forwards or backwards. One way you will go up a resistor, and the other way you will go down a resistor.

The current in the top resistor is completely unimportant. In fact, since it has an ideal voltage source in parallel, you could remove it and nothing will change in the rest of the circuit. And what is left without that resistor? Another resistor with applied a voltage of 9+9 volts.

@BadUsername Just to be clear, when you stated regarding loop 3 " My question is how can we gain potential energy from a resistor"  Is the resistor you are referring to the one directly connected across the upper battery?

@BadUsername I need an answer to my question. WHICH resistor are you talking about.

@Bob D Yes, the questioner is talking about the resistor connected across the upper battery - the resistor that is in both loop 1 and loop 3 but not in loop 2.

The word needed in the fourth line of text under the diagram is 'respectively', not 'respectfully'.

You might find it instructive to try drawing a 3D landscape representing the circuit. Voltage is height in the landscape. Wires are horizontal paths. Resistors are paths going up or down.  A voltage source is a cliff.

Something I'd recommend is trying to think of electrical circuits with less causality.  Instead of "resistor gives voltage," saying "there is a voltage gain across a resistor" could help.  There's quite a few things in electrical circuits which aren't causal, but instead sort of go together (like V=IR).  Thinking in non-causal terms can help open one's mind to realize how to go about solving problems.

or think of causality the right way. A downhill slope going from left to right can cause a car to roll left to right, but a car rolling right to left does not cause a road to slope upwards. Similarly a voltage potential drop cause a current rather than a current causing a voltage drop.


In the third we get 9 Volts from the battery and from the resistor and
then lose it all to the last resistor. My question is how can we gain
potential energy from a resistor. We must always lose voltage from it.
If I'm missing something please point it out.

I assume you are referring to the resistor connected directly to the upper battery.
It appears you may be interpreting the increase in potential that occurs when one moves in a direction from the negative terminal on the right side of the resistor to the positive terminal on the left side as the resistor physically "supplying" electrical potential energy to the circuit. Pure resistors do not supply energy. They dissipate it.
Instead, when moving from minus to plus in any resistor you should think of it as subtracting the loss of potential energy that occurs due to energy being dissipated the resistor based on the current flowing in the opposite direction through it.
Hope this helps.

I believe 1, 2, and 3 are the loop numbers. Not the values of the currents.

I don't think they were given.  I computed them for made up values of resistors in my answer.

Why, if I may ask? The circuit is quite simple. It's just been drawn with a finger on a smartphone, I think.  And the Op seems to be confused between mesh currents and actual total current.

You seem to be assuming that current flows from right to left in the middle resistor. This is incorrect. The current in loop 1 is twice as large as the current in loop 3 (because both loops are driven by the same battery voltage but loop 3 has twice the resistance of loop 1). So the net current in the middle resistor flows from left to right.
Once you realise that the net current flows from left to right in the middle resistor the you see that there is a net energy loss in this resistor, not a gain.
I suppose you could think of this as being a gain of energy for the loop 3 component of the current and a loss of energy for the opposing loop 1 component of the current, which is twice as large, leading to a net loss of energy - but I think dividing a single current into two opposing parts is a confusing approach here.

"You seem to be assuming that current flows from right to left in the middle resistor." Just out of curiosity, what makes you think the OP assumes that?

Because that's the only way the questioner could conclude that energy is gained in that resistor. Looks like he is considering the loop 3 current alone when he reaches that conclusion.

But he shows the polarity of the resistor plus to minus from left to right which indicates he’s assuming conventional current is flowing from left to right, not from right to left. Then, proceeding counterclockwise in loop three, potential is gained in the upper resistor. Am I missing something?

Also, unless i made a mistake in my loop analysis the loop 3 current is zero and the entire 18V drop is due to the loop 2 current

@BobD Loop 3 current is not zero, but it is half as large as the loop 1 current and in the opposite direction through the middle resistor. The net current in the middle resistor (loop1 - loop 3) goes left to right, from higher voltage to lower voltage, and so loses energy, but the questioner is confused by considering the loop 3 current alone, which goes from right to left in the middle resistor, from lower voltage to higher voltage, and so appears to gain energy.

Found error in my loop equations. Thanks. But my point is the OP is showing the correct polarity for net current flowing left to right in the resistor directly connected to the top battery, is he not?


In loop one the current gains and loses 9 Volts

That's NOT a helpful way to think about this. In general you will not know which way the current flows until you have finished the analysis. For some simple circuits you may be able to squint at it but for anything a little more complex you will have to run the process step by step.
Good practice is:

Draw the schematic cleanly, label all components, voltages and currents uniquely and apply a directional arrow to all to components.
Write out all loop and node equations
Simplify where possible, pick the most suitable set of equations and solve it (typically using a matrix solver).

In your case you actual CAN squint. Let's assume both resistors are  $1\Omega$. The voltage across the horizontal resistor , $R_H$ is 9V so the current is $9A$.  The voltage across the vertical resistor , $R_V$ is 18V so the current is $18A$.
In the third loop you have 18 Amps coming out of the lower source. At the first node, 9Amps go into $R_H$ and 9Amps go into the other source. At the second node the 9Amp branches sum up to 18 Amps again and that goes back into the source.

Since the top resistor has an ideal voltage source in parallel, its value is irrelevant: the voltage across it is the 9V imposed by the top battery, and the current through it will be 9V/Rtop.
Exactly because the top battery will set the voltage, regardless of the top resistor's value, we can remove the resistor without altering the variables in the rest of the circuit. In this simplified circuit, the side resistor will see the sum of the two battery voltages across it, so it will have 18V across it and a current 18V/Rside.
There, you have solved the circuit in your head.
All is left is to compute the current in the top battery. Apply KCL and you will see it has to be the sum of the currents flowing in the resistors.
For example, if Rtop=Rside=R=9 ohms, we have IRtop=1A from + to -, and IRmid=2A from + to -, while Ibatt= 3A from - to +. The current from the positive electrode of the top battery will split and go in part in the side resistor and in part in the top resistor.
Now, to your question:
Note how the total current shows an inversion in direction along part of loop 3, that is along the path going through side resistor, side battery, and top resistor. This is the part that confuses you, I think. Well, probably not the total current in itself, but the mesh current you seem to believe it should be equal to.
The mesh current in that mesh is not the total current, neither in value, nor in sign.
If you compute correctly the magnitude and direction of the (partial) mesh current you will see that you have a voltage drop in the top resistor as well.
Can you do it by yourself?

The circuit is relatively simple and does not really require loop analysis techniques. A simple analysis is as follows:

First we nominate a section to be the zero reference voltage. (It can be any segment or junction, as the end result is the same.) In fig 1 the bottom left segment in red is chosen as the reference section. The voltages of the other sections simply result from increasing the voltage by 9v at each battery. The current through each resistor is simply obtained from Ohm's law. The current loops are completed using KCL and the common sense principles that currents only flow in a single direction through any given circuit component and that current flows from high potential to low potential. The result is there is only inner loop 1, outer loop 2 and no anticlockwise loop 3. The complete circuit can be explained without any need for requiring currents to flow from low to high potential and there is no gain in energy in any of the resistors. The batteries increase the potential energy and resistors can only dissipate energy so the potential across a resistor can only decrease in the direction of the current flow.
The loop flows obtained from standard loop analysis should not be considered as literal current flows and should be treated with caution. They are basically mathematical abstractions that help analysis.
